# EJB Session bean is not bound in JBoss 5 in EAR packaging

Tags: ant, jboss, ejb, ear

I have a dynamic web project which I deploy in EAR format on JBoss 5. Using ant I compile and deploy the ear file on application server. If I deploy EJB and war (client) independently then everything work but when i try to package in ear session bean does not bound. My EJB code and client(Web) are in same project I do not have Independent EJB modules in project. I tried adding jar out of business interface in WEB-INF lib and even in lib directory of ear file but nothing worked. I want to know If EJB jar is not in the class path and how to set order of modules in ear file?

application.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" id="Application_ID" version="5">
  <display-name>X3</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>x3.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>x3</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
        <ejb>x3.jar</ejb>
    </module>
</application>
```

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<project name="x3" default="all" basedir=".">

    <property name="compiledWebClasses" value="${basedir}/build/classes" />
    <property name="dist" value="${basedir}/dist" />
    <property name="descriptors" value="${basedir}/dd" />
    <property name="build" value="${basedir}/build" />

    <property name="JBOSS_CLIENT_LIB" value="C:\jboss5dummy\jboss-5.0.1.GA\client" />
    <property name="JBOSS_LIB" value="C:\jboss5dummy\jboss-5.0.1.GA\lib" />
    <property name="JBOSS_COMMON_LIB" value="C:\jboss5dummy\jboss-5.0.1.GA\common\lib" />


    <path id="compile.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${JBOSS_CLIENT_LIB}">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>

        <fileset dir="${JBOSS_LIB}">
                    <include name="*.jar"/>
                </fileset>

            <fileset dir="${JBOSS_COMMON_LIB}">
                        <include name="*.jar"/>
                    </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${basedir}/build" />
        <delete dir="${basedir}/dist" />
    </target>

    <target name="createFolders">
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/build/classes" />
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/dist" /> 
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes" debug="true">
            <classpath refid="compile.classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="jar">
            <jar jarfile="${build}/x3.jar">
                <fileset  dir="${compiledWebClasses}">
                        <include name="**/ejb/**"/>
                </fileset>
                <metainf dir="${descriptors}">
                    <include name="persistence.xml"/>
                </metainf>
            </jar>
    </target>

    <fileset dir="${compiledWebClasses}" id="warClasses.fileset">
        <include name="**/controller/**" />
    </fileset>

    <target name="war">
        <war destfile="${build}/x3.war" webxml="${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="${basedir}/WebContent"/>
            <classes refid="warClasses.fileset"/>
        </war>
    </target>

    <target name="ear">
            <jar destfile="${dist}/x3.ear">
                <metainf dir="${descriptors}">
                    <include name="application.xml"/>
                    <include name="jboss-app.xml"/>                
                 </metainf>
                <fileset file="${build}/x3.war"/>
                <fileset file="${build}/x3.jar"/>

            </jar>
        </target>

    <target name="all" depends="clean, createFolders, compile, jar, war, ear">
        <echo message="done" />
    </target>

</project>
```

jboss-app.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<jboss-app>
    <loader-repository>dev.lmd.com:loader=x3.ear</loader-repository>
</jboss-app>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<persistence version="2.0"  
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">  
 <persistence-unit name="StudentMgtPU"  
  transaction-type="JTA">  
  <jta-data-source>java:/StudentMgtDS</jta-data-source>  
  <properties>  
   <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />  
   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />  
  </properties>  
 </persistence-unit>  
</persistence>
```

Business Interface

```
package com.lmd.dev.ejb.session;  

import javax.ejb.Local;  

import com.lmd.dev.ejb.domain.Student;  

@Local  
public interface ManageStudentSessionBeanLocal {  
 public boolean addStudent(Student Student);  
}
```

Business Logic

```
package com.lmd.dev.ejb.session;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import com.lmd.dev.ejb.domain.Student;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class ManageStudentSessionBean
 * 
 * @author Sameera Jayasekara
 */
@Stateless
public class ManageStudentSessionBean implements ManageStudentSessionBeanLocal {

 @PersistenceContext
 private EntityManager entityManager;

 public boolean addStudent(Student student) {
     System.out.println("Trying .............");
  entityManager.persist(student);
  return true;
 }

}
```

Servlet (Client)

```
package com.lmd.dev.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.lmd.dev.ejb.domain.Student;
import com.lmd.dev.ejb.session.ManageStudentSessionBeanLocal;

/**
 * 
 * 
 * 
 */
public class ManageStudentServlet extends HttpServlet {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @EJB(mappedName="ManageStudentSessionBean/local")
 private ManageStudentSessionBeanLocal manageStudentSessionBeanLocal;

 public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

  super.init(config);

 }

 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

 }

 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

  String message = "";

  String firstName = request.getParameter("fname");
  String lastName = request.getParameter("lname");
  String email = request.getParameter("email");

  Student student = new Student();
  student.setFirstName(firstName);
  student.setLastName(lastName);
  student.setEmail(email);

  if (manageStudentSessionBeanLocal != null && manageStudentSessionBeanLocal.addStudent(student)) {
      message = "Student Successfuly Added";
  } else {
      message = "Student Adding Failed";
  }

  request.setAttribute("message", message);
  RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
  rd.forward(request, response);

 }

}
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>x3</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ManageStudentServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ManageStudentServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.lmd.dev.controller.ManageStudentServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ManageStudentServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ManageStudentServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

You can find source code on git as well

[Source Code](https://github.com/virendra656/eardeployment)

Comment: Have you tried [injecting the EJB](https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/Injecting_EJB_in_Servlets.html) by adding `@Stateless(name="manageStudentSessionBean")` to the EJB module instead of just `@Stateless` and in your servlet use the annotation  `@EJB(name = "manageStudentSessionBean")` above the entry `private ManageStudentSessionBeanLocal manageStudentSessionBeanLocal = null;`

Comment: Thanks for help but sadly it did not work. Does ejb module goes into the class path? You know when I try to deploy war and ejb module independently by adding ejb module in the class path to war then it works.

Comment: I dont believe it needs to go into classpath.  Do you have a web.xml in the WAR's WEB-INF folder, as per the linked article "For the injection to take place in a web module, your web.xml should use the 2.5 version of the web-app xsd" - can you try creating that file with the XML they show in the important section?

Comment: @JGlass I have added web.xml structure in the question and yes it uses 2.5 version. I think client should have the ejb module in the class path in order to deploy and compile.

Comment: Understood on the web.xml.  I believe with the JBoss class loader, the EJB Module would already be in the classpath - are you referring to adding it as a class patch entry in the web apps META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file?  None of my projects have this listing, but a number of them were in the process of being upgraded to JBoss 7.  What output in the server.log file is shown when you deploy the application?

Comment: Let me know if you get it working and what the issue was if you dont mind!  I dont mind helping you continue to troubleshoot!

Comment: sorry last night I fell asleep in the morning I figured out what went wrong actually when we deploy EJB in EAR then entries becomes different in console . 
x3/ManageStudentSessionBean/local - EJB3.x Default Local Business Interface

x3/ManageStudentSessionBean/local-com.sameera.session.ManageStudentSessionBeanLocal - EJB3.x Local Business Interface
@EJB(mappedName="ManageStudentSessionBean/local")

Yesterday Code.

@EJB(mappedName="ManageStudentSessionBean/local")

So I added ear name in the mapped name and it worked.

@EJB(mappedName="x3/ManageStudentSessionBean/local")

Comment: @JGlass You were right there's no need to add business interface jar in WEB-INF/lib. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Glad you figured it out with a tiny bit of help - may I recommend you try and "answer" your question - then if others have a similar issue you can list exactly what worked!

Comment: Your hint for logs saved my time  I answered it.

Comment: Glad you got it solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we package an EAR file out of EJB modules then lookup method for the client changes slightly. We can always check it in the console what path we should refer to for injection.Look up method for EJB injection in Servlet for EAR packaging would be something like this.

```
@EJB(mappedName="YOUR_EAR_NAME/ManageStudentSessionBean/local")
```